# Android IntentService bluetooth radio

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver, estimote

I'm using the Estimote SDK to monitor for bluetooth pings when entering and exiting regions. It was working correctly when I had all the scanning and notification code in my Activity, but as soon as the app was no longer in the foreground it stopped. So I'm trying to set up a service so the bluetooth scanning carries on in the background until I click a button to stop it. I have my activity and the service classes below but when I try to debug the app its not even starting the scanning process, I get the message:

```
I/EstimoteSDK: com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService.onCreate:305 Creating service
D/BluetoothAdapter: 811314615: getState() :  mService = null. Returning STATE_OFF
```

For some reason I don't think the service is starting properly, I'm trying to figure out why. Am I using IntentService correctly, I know it stops itself when its work is done, but the scanning process is a loop so it shouldn't finish unless I explicitly tell it to from a component. Am I using the correct type of Service?

Here's my code:

```
// MainActivity.java

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // bool to deal with two listen requests (not implemented yet)
    private static boolean listening = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Get extra data included in the Intent
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                if (message.equals("ENTERED_REGION"))
                {
                    showNotification("Welcome..","to the Access Lab!");
                }
                else if(message.equals("EXITED_REGION"))
                {
                    showNotification("You've left the lab..", "Goodbye!");
                }
            }
        };

         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("Listen"));


        // Long click listener for enabling background monitoring
        fab.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
                startService(myIntent);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Starting..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       //         Snackbar.make(view, "Bluetooth authentication is on", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
       //                 .setAction("Action", null).show();
                return true;
            }
        });


        // click listener to disable background monitoring
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
                stopService(stopIntent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service ended..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      //          Snackbar.make(view, "Bluetooth authentication turned off", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
      //                  .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void showNotification(String title, String message) {
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0,
            new Intent[] { notifyIntent }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

.

```
//BackgroundService.java
import com.estimote.sdk.Beacon;
import com.estimote.sdk.BeaconManager;
import com.estimote.sdk.Region;
import com.estimote.sdk.SystemRequirementsChecker;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;


public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private Region region;

    // default empty constructor
    public BackgroundService()
    {
        super("BackgroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent)
    {
        beaconManager.setMonitoringListener(new BeaconManager.MonitoringListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEnteredRegion(Region region, List<Beacon> list)
            {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("Listen");
                localIntent.putExtra("message", "ENTERED_REGION");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onExitedRegion(Region region)
            {
                Intent localIntent = new Intent("Listen");
                localIntent.putExtra("message", "EXITED_REGION");
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(localIntent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        beaconManager = new BeaconManager(getApplicationContext());
        region = new Region("ranged region",
            UUID.fromString("B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"), 32905, 62058);

        beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceReady() {
                beaconManager.startMonitoring(region);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
    //    beaconManager.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assumption that the scanning process is synchronous is wrong. - Why are you using an IntentService if you want to start and stop it explicitly?

Comment: @JimmyB Yes I thought I should probably be using Service (I tried to use IntentService because Google docs said use Service if you needed multiple requests handled concurrently, which I didn't). What do you mean my assumption of synchronous scanning is wrong?

Comment: Scanning doesn't "loop" until it's done. That happens in the background, so the intent is handled instantly and the service may stop.

Comment: @JimmyB Ok many thanks for a clear explaination, I'll refactor using Service and try again.